# Perform search on State for filtering result react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I wanna implement a live Search function on my `Redux` `State` which I use in my home page via `useSelector`. and when user delete the search content original data show up as well. I use `filter` but the data doesn't affect. how can I achieve that? any help would be appreciated:

```js
const Home = (props) => {

  const companies = useSelector(state => state.companies.availableCompanies); //this is my data
  
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    companies.filter(el => el.name.includes(e));
    console.log(companies) // here I see my data changes but doesn't affect on UI
  }

  return (
      <SearchBar onChangeText={handleSearch} />
      <View style={styles.cardContainer}>  // here I show data.
        {companies.map((el, index) => {
          return (
           <Card
            key={el.id}
            companyId={el.id}
            companyName={el.name}
            companyImage={el.image}
            companyMainAddress={el.mainAddress}
            companyPhoneNumber={el.telephoneNumber}
            companyDetails={el.details}
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate('CardDetails', {
              id: el.id,
              companyName: el.name,
             });
           }}
          />
         )
       })}
     </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with the below changes

Hope it will work for you.

```
const Home = (props) => {

  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState();
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState();
  const companies = useSelector(state => state.companies.availableCompanies); //this is my data
  
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearchQuery(e);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchQuery && typeof searchQuery === "string" && searchQuery.length > 0) {
        const searchData = companies.filter(el => el.name.includes(searchQuery));
        setFilteredData([...searchData]);
    } else {
        setFilteredData();
    }
  }, [searchQuery, companies])

  return (
      <SearchBar onChangeText={handleSearch} />
      <View style={styles.cardContainer}> 
        {(filteredData && Array.isArray(filteredData) ? filteredData : companies).map((el, index) => {
          return (
           <Card
            key={el.id}
            companyId={el.id}
            companyName={el.name}
            companyImage={el.image}
            companyMainAddress={el.mainAddress}
            companyPhoneNumber={el.telephoneNumber}
            companyDetails={el.details}
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate('CardDetails', {
              id: el.id,
              companyName: el.name,
             });
           }}
          />
         )
       })}
     </View>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer it work, but still I got issues when search result is empty. I need to show nothing when user search fails but here I show all companies. how Can I fix that?

Comment: ok let me update my answer and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

This variable below is a copy of `state.companies.availableCompanies` that is replaced on every render with the original value from `state.companies.availableCompanies`.

```
const companies = useSelector(state => state.companies.availableCompanies); //this is my data
```

Since you're assigning the result of filter to the copy, and not to the original variable inside the redux store. The results are not reflected there, and every time rerender happens, the Functional Component is called again, making all the code inside this function execute again. So, there is a new variable companies that is not related to the old one.

To actually update the original variable inside redux. You need to create a redux action, and dispatch it.

You need to go back and learn the fundamental concepts of redux before proceeding with this.

Here is the link to the documentation explaining how the data flow works in redux.
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-2-concepts-data-flow

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useDispatch()` to get dispatcher and dispatch an action to your reducer with state to update in your `handleSearch ()`

Something like:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const handleSearch = (e) => {
   dispatch({type:"YOUR_ACTION",payload:companies.filter(el => el.name.includes(e))})
    console.log(companies) ;
  }
```

Refer: https://medium.com/@mendes.develop/introduction-on-react-redux-using-hooks-useselector-usedispatch-ef843f1c2561